# TYPO3 t3extblog extension gives set email error

Tags: typo3, blogs

I want to install the TYPO3 blog extension t3extblog. I followed the quick install menu by making the three pages. Meaning the blog with the blog plugin, the subscription manager with the subscription manager plugin and the data folder.

At top level I added the following constant.

```
plugin.tx_t3extblog.persistence.storagePid = 56
plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.blogsystem.pid = 55
plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.subscriptionManager.pid = 57
plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.subscriptionManager.comment.admin.mailTo.email = info@email.nl
```

If I now go the the blog page I'm getting the following error.

> No subscription manager admin email receiver address detected. Make sure plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.subscriptionManager.comment.admin.mailTo.email is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong value set for mailTo, Please check set like below:

```
 plugin.tx_t3extblog.persistence.storagePid = 56
 plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.blogsystem.pid = 55
 plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.subscriptionManager.pid = 57
 plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.emailTo = info@email.nl
```

It will works for me.

Comment: Tried that before and just again, but still receive the same error message.

Comment: Please try this instead of above line:
plugin.tx_t3extblog.settings.emailTo = info@email.nl